# Unix: Bash:Searching for specific directories

Tags: bash, unix

I am working on a script in Bash and I am trying to find specific directories. I am very close, I am just stuck.

I am searching for directories that have one to three digits in their name.

Ex: Ex1, Ex23,Ex456.

When I fined these directories, I want to run a certain script.

I can get it to go through all single digit directories, but when I try to do get my script to do more than one digit, it does not work.

Edit: When I say it doesn't work, it will run and find a directory with 3 digits in it, but it ignores all directories with two or one digit.

Script:

```
for directory in  Ex[0-9][?0-9][?0-9]/
do
    ./test "$directory"
    echo "Directory is: " $directory
done
```

Comment: Use three globs. `for directory in Ex[0-9] Ex[0-9][0-9] Ex[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: @Etan Resiner Wow, I didn't even think of that. It works too. I thought I would just have to use some type of extglob and I couldn't get it to run the way I needed to. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: `Ex[0-9]{1,3}` : Just a guess though. Not sure if it works in shell script.

Comment: @Pramod Karandikar That was my initial thought, but it wouldn't run in a script sadly. More specifically, this happens Ex[0-9]1/  not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to use three globs.

`for directory in Ex[0-9] Ex[0-9][0-9] Ex[0-9][0-9][0-9]`

You could use the `=~` regex matching facilities to do the filtering in the loop instead if you wanted. Something like (untested):

```
for directory in  Ex[0-9]*/
do
    if [[ "$directory" =~ Ex[0-9]{1,3} ]]; then
        ./test "$directory"
        echo "Directory is: " $directory
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I forgot about using regex matching.. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 for directory in Ex[0-9]*
    do 
       ./test "$directory"
       echo "Directory is: " $directory
    done
```

Comment: This will match `Ex5foo`, etc. too.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could do:

```
for directory in $(find . -name "Ex[0-9]*" | grep -E "Ex[0-9]{1,3}$")
do
   #My stuff
   ......
done
```